# Partial derivative on convex set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convex-optimization, partial-derivative

If we have a function $f:U  \rightarrow R$ ($U \subset R^n$) which is partially differentiable on a convex set U with $\frac{\delta f}{\delta x_1} = 0$ for all $x \in U$.

How can we prove that $f$ does not depend on $x_1$? It is not clear to me why the domain has to be convex and what if $U$ is just path wise connected?
I would appreciate some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the simple case of $U \subset \mathbb{R}$.  If $U$ is a single interval and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f'(x) = 0$, do you see why $f$ must be constant? If $U$ has multiple connected components, do you see why $f$ does not have to be a constant function?

Now, in the case $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, apply the above results to $f$ restricted to the line starting at $(a,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$ and ending at $(b,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$.  Where is convexity being used?

Comment: Ok, for case n = 1 convex isn't the same as pathwise connected?

Comment: $n=1$ convex is the same as pathwise connected!

Comment: Exactly so if for n = 1 it is the same how could I derive that f is once const and then not necessarily ? I think I am misinterpreting your hint. Could you be more specific?

Comment: In the second and 3rd sentence, I am refering to two different situations:  $U$ is connected, or $U$ is not connected.  If $U$ is not connected, then $f$ needs to be constant on each connected component, but it can be a different constant on each component.

Comment: If $U$ is convex then each point on the line between the start and ending point will also be in U but I still don't see how U being convex implies $f$ does not depend on $x_1$. What am I missing?

Comment: $Df$ restricted to that line is a one variable function whose derivative is $0$, so $f$ is constant along that line.  Thus $f(a,x_2,x_3,...,x_n) = f(b,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$.  This exactly says that $f$ does not depend on $x_1$:  given the same values for $x_2,x_3,...,x_n$, the value for $f$ is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! SO because it is convex we can say it does not depend on $x_1$ but if $U$ is pathwise connected $f$ might be defined on branches along $x_1$, as constant on those branches, thus is will depend of the chioce of $x_1$.